# command sql oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

What is the difference between the following two versions?

The first works, the second is not working.

1)

```
select sum(mont),to_char(datv,'MM')
from vente v
group by to_char(datv,'MM');
```

2)

```
select sum(mont),MONTH(datv)
from vente v
group by MONTH(datv);
```

Comment: MONTH is not a valid Oracle function, unless you define it yourself.

Comment: You're absolutely right. The code I posted in the answer works, but it should be TO_NUMBER...I'll make the edit.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment, MONTH is not a valid Oracle function. That doesn't stop you from defining it yourself:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MONTH (p_date IN DATE) return number
as
  v_month number(2);
begin
  SELECT TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(p_date,'MM')) INTO v_month FROM DUAL;
  return v_month;
end;
/
```

With that, your second query should work now.

Comment: Why are you redefining an existing function ?

Comment: There is no MONTH function in Oracle. You would use to_char(v_date,'MM') to retrieve the month number. However, it comes handy for developers more used to SQL Server syntax, where the MONTH function exists.

Comment: The OP says Oracle, no need to change Oracle to suit MS, is it ? If "developers" can't even type the correct name of a function ..

Comment: He asked why MONTH(date) doesn't work in Oracle. The answer is because MONTH doesn't exist. If he still wants/needs to use it, I pointed out how to do it.

Comment: using `to_number(to_char())` is overly complicated. This can be done using `extract(month from p_date)` You don't also need the `select` at all: `return extract(month from p_date);` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `month()` function in Oracle. If you want the month as a *number*, use `extract()`

```
select sum(mont), extract(month from datv)
from vente
group by extract(month from datv);
```

For more details, please see the manual:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions002.htm#SQLRF20033